# how to load html with errors in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular6

I am using angular 6. I have a dynamically created HTML file. Which may have errors like:

> self closing tags
>
> closing tags missing
>
> mathematical equations
>
> custom attributes
>
> errors like Template parse errors:
> There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "aff" (

Is there any way to skip all errors and simply load HTML content in angular?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. I haven't test this code.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({ name: 'keepHtml', pure: false })
export class EscapeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
}

  transform(content) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(content);
  }
}
```

[Ref link](https://medium.com/@AAlakkad/angular-2-display-html-without-sanitizing-filtering-17499024b079)

Answer (score 0):

I would first encourage to use nglint in your code .
 From my viewpoint, it is a very bad idea to generate HTML from angular, and I seriously think it will not work at all ! That's is angular job. You have to generate dynamic components . Then, angular will render these components in html.

Comment: sorry its not like that , i create html externally  and i want to load that html in angular.  this html have some errors because of that i cant load webpage it in angular.thats the problem :(

Comment: so, refine your question please

Answer (score 0):

Use an html validator after generating  the html page, that will permit to fix it.